# IBKR Cash Accounts

Tags: day-trading

Scenario is for day trading with IBKR Cash Accounts. Let's say I purchase one stock of ABC at $100 and then sell(on the same day) when the price reaches $103. After this is done, since I am selling at a profit, will the original $100(minus commissions) used to make the purchase be returned to my cash account instantaneously, or do I have to wait for two days?
I am asking because of the T+2 days rule which I am confused about.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to wait

Comment: Settlement for stock is two days for a cash account.

Comment: Okay, so two days, got it.